# Image Icon isn't appearing

Tags: java, swing, imageicon

I'm trying to make a very basic game where a spaceship moves around but the spaceship icon isn't displaying. This is the code, could someone please help me?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

public class MyFrame extends JFrame implements KeyListener{


    JLabel Rocket;
    ImageIcon rocketImage;



    MyFrame(){
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setSize(1000,1000);
        this.setLayout(null);
        this.addKeyListener(this);

        rocketImage = new ImageIcon("resources/rocket.png");


        Rocket = new JLabel();
        Rocket.setBounds(0, 0, 100, 100);
        Rocket.setIcon(rocketImage);
        Rocket.setVisible(true);



        this.add(Rocket);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        //keyTyped = Invoked when a key is typed. Uses KeyChar, char output
        switch (e.getKeyChar()) {
            case 'a' -> Rocket.setLocation(Rocket.getX() - 10, Rocket.getY());
            case 'w' -> Rocket.setLocation(Rocket.getX(), Rocket.getY() - 10);
            case 's' -> Rocket.setLocation(Rocket.getX(), Rocket.getY() + 10);
            case 'd' -> Rocket.setLocation(Rocket.getX() + 10, Rocket.getY());
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        //keyPressed = Invoked when a physical key is pressed down. Uses KeyCode, int output
        switch (e.getKeyCode()) {
            case 37 -> Rocket.setLocation(Rocket.getX() - 10, Rocket.getY());
            case 38 -> Rocket.setLocation(Rocket.getX(), Rocket.getY() - 10);
            case 39 -> Rocket.setLocation(Rocket.getX() + 10, Rocket.getY());
            case 40 -> Rocket.setLocation(Rocket.getX(), Rocket.getY() + 10);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        
    }
}
```

Thanks in Advance

The image isn't appearing but when the label is a just a coloured square it appears. I think it's something with Image Icon

Comment: I would guess your directory in not on your classpath. Use `ImageIO` to read the image. You will get an error if the image can't be found.

Comment: Better to load your files/images as resources:
[Netbeans](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/78-loading-files-as-resources-in-java-with-netbeans)
[Eclipse](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/80-loading-files-as-resources-in-java-with-eclipse)

Comment: Before you do something as advanced as a graphical application, [learn how relative directories work.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory)